# Child processes won't die in Jenkins environment

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm developing code for Linux, and cannot seem to kill processes when running in a Jenkins environment.

I have test script that spawns processes and cleans them up as it goes through the tests. One of the processes also spawns and cleans up one of its own subprocesses. All of the "cleanup" is done by sending a `SIGINT`, followed by a wait. Everything works fine with this when run from a terminal, *except* when running through Jenkins.

When the same exact thing is run in *Jenkins*, processes killed with `SIGINT` do not die, and the call to wait blocks forever. This wreaks havoc on my test. I could update the logic to not do a blocking wait, but I don't feel I should have to change my production code to accommodate Jenkins.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also running in the same problem. A python test script creates a subprocess (lets call it SP)  and later on sends SIGINT to it. The purpose is to verify that the SP code handles SIGINT signal correctly. For some reason this does not work in jenkins. As you have described, calling the python script from a terminal works. Calling the python script through ssh also works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In testing, this would usually work when I ran the tests from the command line, but would almost always fail when that unit test script was called from another script. Frankly, it was bizarre....

Then I realized that when I had stray processes, they would indeed go away when I killed them with SIGTERM. But WHY?????

I didn't find a 100%-definitive answer. But thinking about it logically, if the process is not attached to a terminal, then maybe the "terminal interrupt" signal (SIGINT), wouldn't work...?

In doing some reading, what I learned is that, basically, when it's a *shell* that executes a process, the SIGINT action may be set to 'ignore'. That make sense (to me, anyway) because you wouldn't want CTRL-C at the command line to kill all of your background processes:

> When the shell executes a process “in the background” (or when another background process executes another process), the newly executed process should ignore the interrupt and quit characters. Thus, before a shell executes a background process, it should set SIGINT and SIGQUIT to SIG_IGN.

Our production code isn't a shell, but it is started from a shell, and Jenkins uses /bin/sh to run stuff. So, this would add up.

So, since there is an implied association between SIGINT and the existence of a TTY, SIGTERM is a better option for killing your own background processes:

> It should be noted that SIGINT is nearly identical to SIGTERM. ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal))

I've changed the code that kills the proxyserver processes, and the Python unit test code, to use the SIGTERM signal. Now everything runs at the terminal and in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Process tree killer may be your answer - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller